# Why does my program not accept my boolean result that i am returning?

Tags: java

All i want is to return true if x and y are both "true".

I want to use the switch/case method, instead of a simple if/else.

But i can't get the method to accept my return result.

Do you guys have an idea?

```
 public class test2 {
     public static boolean f(boolean x, boolean y){
        switch(x + "-" + y){            
        case "true-false": 
             return false; //i also tried "return x" or "return y"
        case "false-true": 
             return false;
        case "true-true": 
             return true;
        case "false-false": 
             return false; 
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[]args){
        f(false,true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you return `x && y`?

Comment: The reason this fails is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/11389043 (but I agree with Turing85, you shouldn't do this).

Comment: @AlexB this is not true. If `String`s are used in `switch`, [they are compared as if `equals(...)` is used](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: Didn't know (or expect) this behavior. Thanks! (But now I wonder why the original code didn't work, going to test this now :) )

Comment: @Turing85 Oh man, yes. That is way easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly your code won't compile and also it is not an efficient algorithm.

An efficient algorithm should look like `return x && y` instead of using switch in string.

**No need to convert `boolean` to `string`**. There are various ways of achieving what you are trying to do.

```
public static boolean f(boolean x, boolean y){
    return x && y;
}
```

***Fix compile error by approach #1***

Add `default` case to `switch`, something like below

```
public static boolean f(boolean x, boolean y){

     switch(x + "-" + y){

        case "true-false": 
             return false; //i also tried "return x" or "return y"
        case "false-true": 
             return false;
        case "true-true": 
             return true;
        case "false-false": 
             return false; 
        default:
            return false;
      }

}
```

***Fix compile error by approach #2***

```
 public static boolean f(boolean x, boolean y){

     switch(x + "-" + y){

            case "true-false": 
                 return false; //i also tried "return x" or "return y"
            case "false-true": 
                 return false;
            case "true-true": 
                 return true;
            case "false-false": 
                 return false; 
          }
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: The cases are exhaustive. The `default`-case is thus superfluous. This does not solve the core-problem.

Comment: Thank you! Now i know that return x && y is way easier, but if i want to use switch/case, all i need to do is add the "default". You guys rock

Comment: @Turing85 Error is caused because of missing default case in this scenario. I agree there is better way of coding this. I try to explain him why switch statement errored out.

Comment: @Turing85 Doesn't it? Now my program runs. If x and y are true, then my program returns true. But of course x&&y is way better.

Comment: The code in the question works as expected, without default, see https://repl.it/repls/GraveCoordinatedGoals. The only thing missing is a return statement (or default) statement to make it compile. In other words: the problem is a compilation problem, not a logic problem.

Comment: @JavaPSPSPS better way to code is x&&y.There are various ways of achieving that you are trying todo.  I explained you with and answer why your code failed.

Comment: While `default` fixes the issue, it is not the only way. Fact is, OPs code does not copile as-is. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531130/4216641) for details.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the program as-is does not compile. The compiler will complain that method `f` is missing a return statement. The `switch` is exhaustive, however the compiler is unable to infer this exhaustiveness and thus complains that there is a missing return if no `case` matches. One possible solution is to add a `default` case as [RamPrakash shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530957/4216641). Another possibility is to add a `return` at the end of the method. In my opinion, both solutions are sub-optimal, more on this later.

With the given fix, the code works as expected. The result is not shown on screen since it is never printed. A slightly modified version of the program gives the expected result:

```
class Ideone {
  public static boolean f(final boolean x, final boolean y) {
    switch (x + "-" + y) {
      case "true-false":
        return false;
      case "false-true":
        return false;
      case "true-true":
        return true;
      case "false-false":
        return false;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f(false, false));
    System.out.println(f(false, true));
    System.out.println(f(true, false));
    System.out.println(f(true, true));
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rluYsn)

---

I would suggest a different solution: instead of constructing a `String`-representation of both parameters, one could just return the AND-product of both parameters: `x && y`. For one, this gets rid of the sub-optimal `return` (albeit it on the end of the method or in the `default`-case). For another, this is more efficient, wrt. computational time and memory consumption.

Comment: Yes, i fully understand that it is way too much code. I was just curious what i did wrong. Thank you for the detailed answer, to my small problem.

Comment: @java looks like you have accepted the wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too complicated and could be simply changed to:

```
 public class test2 {
 public static boolean f(boolean x, boolean y){
    return x && y;
}


public static void main(String[]args){
    f(false,true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There should be a default return statement, it will not compile because it's asking return statement.

```
public class Test {
   public static boolean f(boolean x, boolean y){
        switch(x + "-" + y){
            case "true-false":
                return false; //i also tried "return x" or "return y"
            case "false-true":
                return false;
            case "true-true":
                return true;
            case "false-false":
                return false;
            default: return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(f(false,true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add default in the end of case statement.

```
default:
   return true;
```

and then to see your function returning result in console, use `System.out.println()` to see in console.

```
System.out.println(f(false,true));
```